# Rejoining an embedded infinispan node with the rest of the cluster

Tags: infinispan, jgroups

I have a Java application that runs an embedded infinispan instance. A Jgroups configuration in the app allows infinispan to join other instances of my app running horizontally. So in a cluster of 3 instances there are 3 embedded infinispan instances running at 3 different posts 7800, 7801, 7802.

I use the 'Clumsy' tool to drop traffic to/from my third node's 7802 port and then as expected my other two nodes will have their nodeRemoved() listener methods fired which is great. (Note that node 3 is still running, its just that I have switched off its local/internet traffic for its infinispan port to simulate isolation)

Now, if I re-enable traffic on Node 3's 7802 port, I notice that infinispan there never seems to properly rejoin or trigger nodeAdded() in the other nodes.

I am wondering what I am missing

infinispan.xml and jgroups stack , which I have swapped out for now

```
<infinispan xmlns="urn:infinispan:config:13.0"
            xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
            xsi:schemaLocation="urn:infinispan:config:13.0
                                https://infinispan.org/schemas/infinispan-config-13.0.xsd">

    <jgroups>
        <!-- Creates a custom JGroups stack named "my-stack". -->
        <!-- Inherits properties from the default TCP stack. -->
        <stack name="my-stack">
            <TCP
                    bind_addr="${jgroups.bind_addr:site_local}"
                    bind_port="${jgroups.bind_port:7800}"
                    recv_buf_size="${tcp.recv_buf_size:130k}"
                    send_buf_size="${tcp.send_buf_size:130k}"
                    max_bundle_size="64K"
                    sock_conn_timeout="300"
                    thread_pool.min_threads="0"
                    thread_pool.max_threads="20"
                    thread_pool.keep_alive_time="30000"/>
            <RED/>


            <TCPPING async_discovery="true"
                     initial_hosts="172.26.240.1[7800],172.26.240.1[7801],172.26.240.1[7802]"
                     port_range="2"/>
            <MERGE3 min_interval="10000"
                    max_interval="30000"/>
            <FD_SOCK/>
            <FD_ALL timeout="9000" interval="3000"/>
            <VERIFY_SUSPECT timeout="1500"/>
            <BARRIER/>
            <pbcast.NAKACK2 use_mcast_xmit="false"
                            discard_delivered_msgs="true"/>
            <UNICAST3/>
            <pbcast.STABLE desired_avg_gossip="50000"
                           max_bytes="4M"/>
            <pbcast.GMS print_local_addr="true" join_timeout="2000"/>
            <UFC max_credits="2M"
                 min_threshold="0.4"/>
            <MFC max_credits="2M"
                 min_threshold="0.4"/>
            <FRAG2 frag_size="60K"/>
            <!--RSVP resend_interval="2000" timeout="10000"/-->
            <COUNTER bypass_bundling="true" timeout="5000"/>


            <pbcast.STATE_TRANSFER/>
        </stack>
    </jgroups>

    <cache-container>

        <metrics gauges="false" histograms="false"/>


        <transport stack="tcp" cluster="${cluster.name}" initial-cluster-size="1"/>
<!--        <transport stack="my-stack" cluster="${cluster.name}" initial-cluster-size="1"/>-->
        <serialization marshaller="org.infinispan.commons.marshall.JavaSerializationMarshaller">
            <allow-list>
                <regex>.*</regex>
            </allow-list>
        </serialization>

        <distributed-cache name="my-sessions">
            <encoding>
                <key media-type="application/x-java-serialized-object"/>
                <value media-type="application/x-java-serialized-object"/>
            </encoding>
        </distributed-cache>

        <!-- A map which is used for cluster-wide properties. -->
        <distributed-cache name="cluster-properties">
            <encoding>
                <key media-type="application/x-java-serialized-object"/>
                <value media-type="application/x-java-serialized-object"/>
            </encoding>
        </distributed-cache>

        <!-- A map which is used for cache synchronization. -->
        <replicated-cache name="pl-commit-messages">
            <encoding>
                <key media-type="application/x-java-serialized-object"/>
                <value media-type="application/x-java-serialized-object"/>
            </encoding>
        </replicated-cache>



    </cache-container>
</infinispan>
```

Comment: Can you add the JGroups configuration? And version?